# How to redirect HTTP to HTTPS using XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I'm trying to redirect HTTP to HTTPS using XAMPP.
I've already seen all questions and multiple answers on multiple websites recommending this website: *[XAMPP: SSL Encrypt the Transmission of Passwords with HTTPS | Rob's Notebook](https://robsnotebook.com/xampp-ssl-encrypt-passwords)*

### This is what I did:

---

I uncommented the line:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

in  `C:/xampp/apache/config/httpd.conf`  by removing the `#` in front of it.

Then I typed this inside of `C:/xampp/apache/config/extra/httpd-xampp.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect /xampp folder to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} xampp
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]

    # Redirect /phpMyAdmin folder to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} phpmyadmin
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]

    # Redirect /security folder to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} security
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]

    # Redirect /webalizer folder to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} webalizer
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

I triple-checked that I did everything correctly, I saved everything, and I restarted XAMPP, but still, I'm not able redirected to HTTPS. Please Help!

Comment: `if( !isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) )` then you can simply use your `header('Location: https://...'); exit();`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20730778/how-to-enable-ssl-only-on-specified-xampp-directories

Comment: user2078421 That's exactly what I tried, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: You should describe precisely what redirects you are trying to achieve. Your example code is doing more than simply redirecting HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: w3dk What else is it doing then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself; I had vhosts setup and I had to place

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect /xampp folder to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} xampp
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]

# Redirect /phpMyAdmin folder to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} phpmyadmin 
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]

# Redirect /security folder to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} security
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]

# Redirect /webalizer folder to https 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} webalizer
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Inside the directory I want redirected in *C:/xampp/apache/config/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf*.

This explained in the last few lines of robs notebook:
*One thing to keep in mind with this redirection is that if you have virtual hosts, you need to place the redirection code (with the RewriteCond and RewriteRule) inside of your virtual host declarations, otherwise the redirection won’t work.*

Comment: Your 4 rules could be greatly simplified, as a single rule. However, your existing directives redirect more than just the "`/xampp` folder" etc. And if you are using virtual hosts then you should be able to avoid the check for HTTPS. (?)

Comment: so we don't have to make any changes in httpd.config?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Config SSL for domain in `xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf`

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
    DocumentRoot "/your/project/path"
    ServerName  yourdomain.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/your/ssl/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/your/ssl/server.key"
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "C:/xampp/apache/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Step 2:** Now config to redirect http to https in `xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    ServerName yourdomain.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

**Step 3:** Restart Xampp